# How to restore Option-letter in AquaEmacs to type Unicode letters?

Tags: mac, emacs, unicode, aquamacs

I would like to use my regular Option + letter (i.e. ł = Option + L) to input such a letter to emacs (in latex mode). How to do it? Now it is overridden by jump to next word on the left.

btw. when I open a file containing such a letters they are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> (or the *Options* > *Option Key* submenu) to toggle the meaning of the actual Option key. By default it switches between “Mac OS X extended character mode” and “Emacs Meta key mode”

It seems like you have “Meta mode” active (*Options* > *Option Key* > *Meta*), but you probably want the “extended character mode” (*Options* > *Option Key* > *Standard Mac Characters*).

In Aquamacs Emacs M-l (“Meta ell”) is probably bound to the downcase-word function, which looks like “move one word to the right” if the word is already in lowercase.

Comment: I had the opposite problem, that is, my aquamacs suddenly started using meta for characters, and I was lost, as I couldn't do my "M-x foobar", "M-v" and "M-w", among others. Your answer was really helpful and solved my problem in seconds. Thank you!